# Generics and methods in java

Tags: java, generics

I´ve got a problem to solve in java. 
Theres is a method, that got a Object as parameter. And in that method, there is a if statement. But i can´t use the if statement. We have to use the T generic in that class, so I want to compare 2 objects of the same type, but on other, he doesnt want to get the getAge() method.
Maybe u guys have some ideas? Here´s some code.

```
public boolean isOlder(T other) {
        if(this.getAge() > other.getAge()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: (How) Is the object of type T guaranteed to provide a getAge method? Probably the use of a generic type does not make sense here.

Comment: Please add some context as to what is the class definition and what exactly is calling the method.

Comment: I suspect something like `T extends someObject` is required, where `someObject` has the `getAge()` method

Comment: @jr593 more like `T extends SomeClass` :)

Comment: @floxbr yes maybe it doesnt make sense, but our prof wants us to do, so... i have to.
Thank u all. It helped me a lot. Didnt know, that i can extend to the class, where it is overwriten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless explicitly told otherwise, generic type would be expected to be a child of `Object`, which would not have `getAge()` method.

What you probably want to do is:

```java
//provided that we have somewhere
public class BaseClass {
...
  public int getAge() ....
...
}

// you can write method like this:
public <T extends BaseClass> boolean isOlder(T other) {
        if(this.getAge() > other.getAge()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
} 

// you can also simplify method:
public <T extends BaseClass> boolean isOlder(T other) {
        return this.getAge() > other.getAge();
} 

// This also might work for you (no generics at all)
public boolean isOlder(BaseClass other) {
        return this.getAge() > other.getAge();
}
```

More information:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: Are you sure that `other.getAge()` will compile when you declared it as `Class<T> other`?

Comment: BTW small tip for OP: `if(condition) return true; else return false` can be simplified to `return condition;`

Comment: @Pshemo - yes, it would be safer to use just `T other`, I have updated the comment.

Comment: What would be the advantage over isOlder(BaseClass other)? T is not used anywhere...

Comment: @floxbr I don't see any advantage in this code. The author explicitly asked about generics, though, so I'd assume there going to be an advantage in the bigger picture. I have added an option `isOlder(BaseClass other)` for a better picture anyway.